# how to fix my nested for statement in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a process control sheet to practice vba but I've found out that the chunk I've coded doesn't work well.

What I want is a calendar which is automatically printing months, days, and dates next to next from the year I've written in specific cell.

like this

[image]

but the result is that the day and date are overwritten in only one cell.

[image]

I don't know why it doesn't work.

```
Public Sub automateCalendar()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Dim checkYear As Integer
    Dim lastDay As Integer


    checkYear = Cells(1, "B").Value
    lastDay = Day(DateSerial(checkYear, i + 1, 0))


    Dim lastDayColumn As Long
    Dim lastMonthColumn As Long


    Dim dateCheck As String


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For i = 1 To 12
        For j = 1 To lastDay
            lastDayColumn = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Cells(4, lastDayColumn + 1).Value = j

            If j = 1 Then
                Cells(4, lastDayColumn + 1).Offset(-1, 0).Value = i
                lastMonthColumn = Cells(3, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            End If

            If j = lastDay Then
                With Range(Cells(3, lastMonthColumn), Cells(3, lastDayColumn + 1).Offset(-1, 0))
                    .Merge
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .Font.Size = 20
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With

                With Columns(lastDayColumn).Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                    .ColorIndex = 0
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                    .Weight = xlThick
                End With

            End If


            dateCheck = Format(DateSerial(checkYear, i, j), "aaa")

            If dateCheck = "Sat" Or dateCheck = "Sun" Then
                Cells(4, lastDayColumn + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                With Cells(4, lastDayColumn + 1).Offset(1, 0)
                    .Value = dateCheck
                    .Font.Color = vbRed
                End With
            Else
                Cells(4, lastDayColumn + 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = dateCheck
            End If

        Next j
    Next i

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I've edited this article and added some pics which make you understandable please help me.

Comment: The code worked for me... *After* I fully qualified the `Cells` with the worksheet. By default, if nothing is specified, Excel takes the first worksheet. So it's much better/safer to specify the worksheet. For example: `Dim ws as Worksheet : Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Name of Sheet"). Then, elsewhere in the code `ws.Cells(1, "B").Value`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help and concern for my question, first of all.

I haven't noticed that vba cannot find the lastcolumn which contains something and I want to set as variable when the last column is hidden.

Only after turning off the hidden property of columns which contain last column, it works well again.

I could have know this fact. :(